# How to make Texmaker on Windows run Bibulous?

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, windows, python, cygwin

I am trying to run [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) with Texmaker on Windows because I want to experiment with it, and I believe I am really close.
Indeed, the only thing I cannot do is to tell Texmaker to run the Python file `bibulous.py` on the `.aux` file during my `pdflatex` `bibtex` `pdflatex`(x2) compilation loop: I get

> Error : could not start the command : python.exe "C:\acertainpath\bibulous.py" "thesis".aux

Following the [WinEdt/Texmaker](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/getting_started.html#modifying-winedt5-to-replace-bibtex-with-bibulous) examples, I replaced the BibteX command by `python.exe "C:\acertainpath\bibulous.py" %.aux`. But maybe that is not the way to do. I am not entirely familiar on how to run things in Python from Windows, nevertheless I made more experiments, and here are some hints:

1. I have Python 3.5 installed, it is in the `AppData` folder. I added it to the `PATH` (as it was proposed during the install process).
   Now I can run python from the `cmd`.
   But then when I just try to run in the `cmd` `python C:\acertainpath\bibulous.py` I get `line 1162 except Exception, err:`. I tried to look in the file but couldn't figure out anything.
   I must add that if I run `python C:\acertainpath\test.py` with `test.py` containing `print("Hello World!")`, Python works, so I don't think the error comes from Python itself.
2. So then I had the idea to run it with Cygwin that I have installed for other reasons. Well, it works with it!
   I can, by just putting the `.aux` files obtained from a `pdflatex` run in Texmaker, along with the `mybst.bst` template file, the `.bib` and the `bibulous.py` all in the Cygwin folder, and running `python bibulous.py thesis.aux`, get the output files necessary (the `.bbl`and the `*-extract.bib`).
    If I put them back in `C:\acertainpath` where my thesis and `bibulous.py` were originally, running `pdflatex`(x2) gives me my pdf!
   I also want to say that if I run in Cygwin `python bibulous.py`(the equivalent of what I tried in point 1. in `cmd`), it works, and by that I mean Bibulous exectues and of course then fails because there is no `.aux` file, but it works.

So in the end I feel like it's the way I call it from Windows (and so also from Texmaker) that is at fault. Maybe I should do something else here?

Comment: The `bibulous.py` file is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nzhagen/bibulous/master/bibulous.py)

Comment: I did a slight edit for clarity

Comment: Try it with python 2.7.  Python 2 and python 3 have some differences.  It wouldn't surprise me if cygwin had 2.7 (mine does).  You can check by just typing `python` from your cygwin prompt.

Comment: ... but your intial error may have an issue with quotes as well -- I'd expect `"thesis.aux"` or `thesis.aux` (or even just `thesis`  or `"thesis"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a Python version problem, because with Python 2.7 it works! (it is also indeed the version Cygwin was using!)

Comment: Another comment now: do I really have to run `pdflatex` twice after Bibulous? (you can post an answer so I can accept it btw)

Comment: The reason for running pdflatex twice is cross referencing. Run from the command line it warns you if you need to run it again, but in general after the any bibliography software you do need to

Comment: Note that the Bibulous project is currently working on implementing compatibility with both Python 2.7 and 3.5, so that should be available soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python versions are rather confusing.  When "2.7 or greater" is specified, compatibility with 3.x isn't guaranteed, and is actually unlikely.

Cygwin currently includes 2.7 which is why it worked there, while most python distributions for Windows default to 3.5.

So the solution is probably to install python 2.7, though it may be installed already and just need to be configured.